# Como recorrer una tabla para obtener el value de cada botón con Javascript

Tags: javascript, mvc

Tengo una `tabla` con varias filas, cada fila tiene un `botón`"eliminar" con un `value = idLibro` diferente. Al final de la tabla tengo un botón "Comprar". Necesito que en el `evento onclick` de este `boton` "comprar" pasarle la `tabla` a una función de `javascript` para obtener el `value` de c/u de los botones"eliminar". cada valor del `value`lo pasaría a un `array`. Después pasaría este `array` al `controlador`.

Aclaro que soy novato en javascript. Mi pregunta es ¿De que forma puedo pasarle la `tabla` a una función de `javascript` para recorrerla y así obtener el `value` de cada `boton`"Eliminar" que esta en c/u de las filas?

Esta es la función que me crea la tabla

```js
function createSelectedTable(arreId, arreNames) {

        var tamNames = arreNames.length;

        var table = '<table cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="tablaSeleccionados"><thead bgcolor="#2E4053"><tr><th scope="col" style="color:#ECF0F1">Libros seleccionados</th><th scope="col" style="color:#ECF0F1">Accion</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr></tr>';

        for (var e = 0; e < tamNames; e++) {

            table += '<tr>';
            table += '<td>' + arreNames[e] + '</td>';
            table += "<td><button onclick='deleteRow(this);' class='boton2 btn' id='" + arreNames[e] + "'" + " value='" + arreId[e] + "'" + ">Eliminar</button></td>";
            table += '</tr>';          
        };

        table += '</tbody></table>';

        $('#miDiv').html(table);//muestra la tabla en el div #miDiv
        //guarda la tabla en una sessionStorage
        sessionStorage.setItem('tablaSeleccionados', table);

    }
```

Aca el div en donde muestro la tabla, y el boton Comprar

```html
<div id="table-wrapper">
        <div id="table-scroll">
            <div id="miDiv"></div>
            <button onclick="miFuncion();" class="btn btn-info" id="btnComprar" value="" type="button">Comprar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: los id´s de los botones de eliminar son progresivos?

Comment: Gracias por contestar Jack! respecto a tu pregunta depende, por ejemplo esta el id 18, 19 y después aparece el 23, 24,25 y 39. Entonces si te referís a progresivo que va de menor a mayor es un si, ahora si te referis a que si los id son consecutivos la respuesta seria no.

Comment: Observaciónes: 1. en el tbody tienes un `<tr></tr>` vacío. Tendrías que corregir eso. 2. Tu pregunta dice que tienes que recorrer una tabla. Supongo que es la tabla creada con la función  `createSelectedTable`. En este caso para poder recorrerla tendrías primero que asegurarte que la tabla ya está creada

Comment: Gracias @enxaneta por las observaciones! y como recorro a la tabla para obtener el value de cada botón?

Comment: El valor del botón es `arreId[e]` . En lugar de recorrer la tabla podrías recorrer el array

Comment: gracias! si había pensado eso, pero bueno me gustaba la idea de poder recorrer la tabla y obtener el value de cada botón como aprendisaje también.